# Sum of infinite telescoping series $\sum_{r=2}^\infty \frac{1}{r^2-1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, telescopic-series

How do I find sum of $\sum_{r=2}^\infty \frac{1}{r^2-1}$? The answer given in my book is 3/4. I can decompose the general term into $(\frac{1}{r-1}-\frac{1}{r+1})$ multiplied by 1/2 but since it is infinite I don't know what to do next. How should  I do this?

Comment: Just try to write terms : $1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{5}$ you will see the terms , which removes

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/249040, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1624203 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Br%3D2%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Br%5E2-1%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: @gimusi: These answers (for example) https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1624210, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/249061/42969 to the duplicates explain the limiting process in detail.

Comment: @gimusi: I disagree. Identical questions should be closed as duplicates, so that all information about a problem is collected in one place. That is *better* for the site, not worse. If you *know* that your hint *"is the billion duplicate of other answer"* then you should not answer but vote to close. (With your attitude no question would be closed as duplicate ever.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let consider

$$\sum_{r=2}^n \frac{2}{r^2-1}=\sum_{r=2}^n(\frac{1}{r-1}-\frac{1}{r+1})=\sum_{r=2}^n \frac{1}{r-1}-\sum_{r=2}^n \frac{1}{r+1}=$$$$=\sum_{r=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{r}-\sum_{r=3}^{n+1} \frac{1}{r}=1+\frac12-\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}$$

and then take the limit.

Comment: A hint is a simple idea that leads the asker in the right direction, but doesn't actually give them the answer.  Your answer is not a hint, as it goes right to the important part of the argument and does the work for the asker.  Your answer is also not a good answer, as it doesn't finish the computation.  Either give an answer or give a hint, but don't claim that an incomplete answer (albeit one that does all of the heavy lifting) is a "hint".

Comment: @XanderHenderson Yes I agree with you observation and indeed I had a discussion with Martin R now deleted where I've admitted that was not a good idea to add the last part $=1+\frac12-\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}$ to my initial hint since therefore it is almost a full answer. Unfortunately I've misunderstood the result given in the other answer and I was aimed to give a clarification on that.That being said, I think that the hint/answer address perfectly the doubt by the asker had on how to deal with the sum at $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: to calculate the partial sums add the first, third, fifth,... terms and the second, fourth,.. terms.  The answer is $\frac  1 2(1+\frac 1 2)=\frac 3 4$.